# Formula breaks when placed inside arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**Background:** In the formulas below, I am trying to find any number that has the sequential pattern of +1. Example: 1011 (after 10, comes 11) `=(FirstTwo+1=11)=Last 2`.

**Current Formulas:**

- A1 `=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(1000:1011))` //List numbers from 1000 to 1011.
- B1 `=ARRAYFORMULA(LEFT(A1:A,2))` //Only retrieve the first 2 digits.
- C1 `=ARRAYFORMULA(RIGHT(A1:A,2))` //Only retrieve the last 2 digits.
- D1 `=ARRAYFORMULA(if((B1:B12+1=C1:C12),TRUE,FALSE))` // If first 2 digits +1 = last 2 digits, TRUE.

**Expected Outcome:** D12 = TRUE

**Actual Outcome:** D12 = FALSE

**My only found solution (not a good one)**

1. Delete formula in C1.
2. Manually type each number in column C (resulting in C12 containing "11")
3. And now the array formula works for D1, and correctly applied TRUE in D12.

**Why cant I achieve the same results using the formula in C1?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the output data type is text and not an integer. You can test it by using the function `type()`. [Reference document link](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267375?hl=en-GB).

You can fix it by multiplying the outputs by 1. Eg.:

B1: `=ARRAYFORMULA(LEFT(A1:A,2)*1)`

C1: `=ARRAYFORMULA(RIGHT(A1:A,2)*1)`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for catching that. Your solution does solve the question, however it changes some of the formatting of the numbers in C1:C from "01, 02, 03" to "1, 2, 3". Is there any way for to keep the 0 in front? - Reason: I have another column which finds repetitive patterns such as "2020" (=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(((A1:A)=(B1:B)),TRUE,))). Thanks for your help. This has been driving me crazy.

Comment: I would use 2 sets of columns in that case. One for the math and have integers in there. And one for the string matching and have the "0X" string in there. The column can *look* like a "0X" column (by custom formatting it as "00") but it won't hold up when you try and match it because fundamentally it is an integer "X".

Comment: Great solution thanks! I took your solution and tweaked it a bit. Instead of having 2 columns as integers, and 2 as text, I took a slightly different approach. 4 columns all integers with single digits in each cell. Solves the issue with the zero needing to be in front. I have a column for each digit A: [=ARRAYFORMULA(LEFT(A1:A,1)*1)] B:[=ARRAYFORMULA(MID(A1:A,2,1)*1)] ...etc. Everything is working perfectly. Thanks for all your help and suggestions :)